# Jquery same height depending on another divs height

Tags: jquery, html, height

Hello i have a problem how to make height of all divs always same height (with class .height-fix) depending on content. Simply if i add more content to one div the rest of them adjust their height.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGLmdb

```
var maxHeight = 0;
  $(".height-fix").each(function(index){
    if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $("this").height();
    }
  });

  $(".height-fix").height(maxHeight);
  console.log(maxHeight);


    <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="jumbotron height-fix">
                <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-3">
             <div class="jumbotron height-fix">
                <p>lorem</p>
                <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="jumbotron height-fix">
                <p>lorem</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="jumbotron height-fix">
                <p>lorem</p>
                <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</p>
                <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: I think you've chosen the tools wrong. It could be easily achieved by CSS3, with [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relpace

maxHeight = $("this").height();

to

maxHeight = $(this).height();

Comment: wtf :D i miss it thaks you much

Answer (score 0):

I simply modify your code a little.

DEMO on [codepen](http://codepen.io/xandershk27/pen/NNZMPr)

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$(".height-fix").each(function(index){
if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
maxHeight = $(this).height();
}
});

$(".height-fix").height(maxHeight);
```